# "CustomEvent is not a constructor" Mozilla Firefox Firebug error messafge

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have the following JavaScript code which results in the "CustomEvent is not a constructor" error message.

```
if (typeof CustomEvent === 'undefined') {
CustomEvent = function(type, eventInitDict) {
            var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
            event.initCustomEvent(type, eventInitDict['bubbles'], eventInitDict['cancelable'], eventInitDict['detail']);
            return event;
        };
    }

window.onload = function (){
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("beforeStartPage", {}));
    PreInitialize();
    if(!IsUnderIpad() || IsIOSPopup()){
        startpage();
    }

    if(!IsUnderIpad()){
        testpage();
    }
}
```

[image]

My guess is that the error which prevents the page from being displayed (only on Firefox and iPad mini Safari) is caused by the way that the CustomEvent function is declared. 
Has anyone come across this issue before? Would you be able to point me into the right direction as to how to fix this problem? I'd appreciate it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=customevent) for CustomEvent

> 1 While a window.CustomEvent object exists, it cannot be called as a
>   constructor. Instead of new CustomEvent(...), you must use e =
>   document.createEvent('CustomEvent') and then e.initCustomEvent(...)

Also, the [MDN document for initCustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/initCustomEvent) seems to be saying that this applies to versions equal to or below Firefox 6.